# fraction of $L^\infty$ functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega $ be a bounded domain of $R^n$, and let $a, b \in L^\infty(\Omega) $ such that $ : \frac{a}{b} 1_{\{x\in \Omega/ b(x)\ne 0\}} \in L^\infty(\Omega).  $

Does the following implication hold ?

for $a.e. \;  x\in \Omega,$ we have :

$$ b(x)=0 \Rightarrow a(x)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

No, certainly not. Notice that having the characteristic function completely ignores where $b(x)=0$, so therefore contains no information about this set. Consider $a\equiv 1$ and $b\equiv 0$. Then the function you described is just the zero function, but the stated implication fails in a big way.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I have to add the assumption that the zero set of $b$ has measure zero.

Comment: Is the assumption that  that the zero set of b has measure zero  necessary to have the implication?

Comment: If the zero set of $b$ has measure zero, then the implication holds trivially (since the implication is true whenever $b(x)\not=0$, hence it holds almost everywhere). It still would have nothing to do with the fact that $\frac{a}{b}1_{\{x\in\Omega\mid b(x)\not=0\}}\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. Like I said in my answer, the characteristic function completely ignores the zero set of $b$.

Comment: @Med: and by the way, it is certainly not necessary for the zero set of $b$ to have measure zero for the implication to hold. Consider $a\equiv 0\equiv b$, then the function is just the constant function 1.